# Rounding latitude longitude locations up/down to approximately 0-1 kilometer to mutual GPS coordinations dot/point

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude, geocoding, geolocation

This is a very simple problem I have to solve simple (in JavaScript, but it doesn't matter for that topic). OK its possible so solve that the hard way, but I just want to solve that as easy as possible with a few lines of code. I don't care if really is a 1000 meters rectangle or 950 meters

Please look at the picture to understand better what I want.
[image]

I want to round up/down the small red dots, which are GPS coordinates within a 1km^2 rectangle/trapez, to the big red dot GPS coordinate. That's it. so basically, every small red dot, should become the same GPS coordinate as the big red dot. Just by rounding to a specific number. I don't know if it should round to the next 6, or next 9 *(I really have no clue about that whole geolocation latitude longitude degree thing)*, or next 60, or next '40 OR 90' (e.g if 100 is 2 kilometer and too much). Just rounding. That's it. Nothing more than that. So that all coordinates within 1km^2 end up after getting rounded as a single GPS coordinate(the big red dot)

But in the longitude latitude (I am really a noob) world you can't measure lat/long to kilometers/meters. Since they are everywhere different long

e.g I have the coordinates `const long = 13.515071931439916; const lat = 52.6245397206283;`

How my code should look like:

```
const latforIf = parseInt(lat, 10);
if ((latforIf < 90 && latforIf >= 85) || (latforIf < -90 && latforIf >= -85)) {
  const bigRedDotGPSCoordinates = // calc, or better said 'round up/down'??
}
if ((latforIf < 85 && latforIf >= 80) || (latforIf < -85 && latforIf >= -80)) {
  const bigRedDotGPSCoordinates = // calc, or better said 'round up/down'??
}
if ((latforIf < 80 && latforIf >= 75) || (latforIf < -80 && latforIf >= -75)) {
  const bigRedDotGPSCoordinates = // calc, or better said 'round up/down'??
}
if ((latforIf < 75 && latforIf >= 70) || (latforIf < -75 && latforIf >= -70)) {
  const bigRedDotGPSCoordinates = // calc, or better said 'round up/down'??
}
// and so on...
```

do you understand what I mean? because kilometers are always different in every latitude, we calc differently in every latitude

Picture of the latitudes. I calc for every latitude (0-10degree, 10-20degree...) differently as you see in the code, because you already know, 1 kilometer is another number of degrees at 80 degree as at 10 degrees:
[image]

I also know that rectangles can't exist on our earth (you cannot make a rectangle grid on our earth) (I read for an hour many stackoverflow threads where [I learned that you cannot fill our earth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24211304/16970415) with rectangles). So don’t worry, it's OK if it's a trapezoid or polygon instead of a rectangle

You're maybe asking yourself why I need this. E.g I have an uber eats app. Users can find restaurants within a range of 15 kilometers. If 2 neighbors search for food, they both make a database call (this is just a use case example. My queries are very expensive because they take long and so on big data aggregations). So since they both want to see the same results and just live 50 meters apart, it's redundant to make 2 database calls. That's why I cache these queries in redis. That's it.

I know I could solve that with additional geoqueries in PostgreSQL; but it does not work for my complicated use case. I really need the solution I've just described.

Comment: Would rounding to two decimals work for you? See here https://xkcd.com/2170/

Comment: @Berend yes!! that's exactly what I want, it's really really simple (y) But I have no experience with coordinates that's why I asked here since you guys know how many degrees are what meters approximately. I don't know how many decimals I want to round, and if I want to round it to 0. Because I don't have a belly feeling how much are 1  kilometer.

Comment: @Berend e.g an example for longitude rounding. I have two points, one has the longitude 52.290155596140295 and one with the longitude 52.29023772194154. I want to round both into one and the same coordinate(big red dot). I want that the maximum amount of rounding is 1 kilometer (it's ok of it is 950 meters). So I want to round both longitudes of them to e.g 52.292 or 52.290 or 52.3. I really dunno since I really have to clue/feeling 'bout these things. This is a really easy problem to solve if you have experience with geo. I maybe explained it too complicated instead of straight forward

Comment: so it's basically a rounding "rule" because it isn't even complex enough to be called an algorithm. As you see in the google maps picture in my post, I just want to have a rounding rule, so that coordinates (the little red ones) within a 1km radius/rectangle/trapez/polygon end up in one and the same coordinate (red big dot). So with rounding/'converting' I want to merge them into a single coordinate. You understand what I mean? The word 'summarize' is maybe a better fit. I want to summarize coordinates within a 1km rectangle/radius into one single coordinate. Through simple basic rounding

Comment: So maybe rounding e.g the coordinate to [52.21722424809167, 0.11736663699232288] to [52.22, 0.12] will do, if it's within 1 kilometer for all values within the range [52.21500000000001-52.21750000000000, 0.11500000000000001]; if it will be too large I gotta round to [52.215, 0.115], or maybe it'll be too big and I even have to round more. This is exactly my question of that entire post. I really did things too complicated, sorry. I just want to know how much to round to stay within approximately 1 kilometer (i also dont care if its now a rectangle trapez or polygon)

Comment: can someone tag @Berend for me? since my account has not enough karma (i think) i can't tag him

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416271/rounding-latitude-longitude-locations-up-down-to-approximately-0-1-kilometer-to i basically had/have that problem, but since it's not possible to grid the earth into 1km rectangles (as you know long/lat ain't always the same size of meters), I just have the idea to round them approximately into mutual coordinate points within a range of 1kilometer. and since the kilometers always vary strongly in every 5degrees step of latitude, I want to always round it differently, depending on where we are (90-85, 85-80... see my code)

Comment: as you already noted yourself, distance between meridians decreases when approaching the poles. So just rounding to [n] decimals won't be precise. However, for your specific problem, it may just be 'good enough'. I don't know how far north (or south) Uber delivers ;-)